# Idioms for when doing something needless when you really have many important things to do first

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Are there English idioms for voicing the needlessness of engaging in a particular, low or no priority action when you already have a number of high priority tasks on your hands?

Comment: There’s “Quit futzing around and get down to business.”

Comment: Most idioms convey the opposite concept : that attention to detail assures overall success.

Comment: *Smoko’s over. Back to work.*

Comment: Procrastination. Or 'displacement activities'. Putting off doing the important things. Skiving off from life for a while. Putting things on the back-burner. Those are mostly neutral-ish. More negative would be 'in denial of the importance of...'

Comment: pencil-sharpening